# how to Concatenate various strings in php with null effect

Tags: php, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have four php variables like: `$abc, $bcd, $dsf, $gkg`. Now I want to concatenate them with a comma separating each.

output:

```
abc,bcd,dsf,gkg
```

Now if any of the variable does not return any value.. then the output is coming like this:

```
abc,,dsf,gkg
```

So what to do to avoid this if value of any variable is null??

```
$street = tribe_get_address( $event->ID );
$city = tribe_get_city( $event->ID );
$state = tribe_get_stateprovince($event->ID);
$country = tribe_get_country( $event->ID );
$zipcode = tribe_get_zip( $event->ID );
$fulladdress= concatenation of these variables..
```

Comment: Show us your current code

Comment: And the code: *concatenation of these variables..* is ... ?

Comment: @Rizier123 code edited above.

Comment: @Rizier123 $fulladdress is the variable which consist of the concatenation  of above 5 strings value.

Comment: how do you concatenate them? Just: `$fulladdress = $var1 . "," . $var, ...` ?

Comment: this is the question only.. how to concatenate these 5 strings given above and then store into $fulladdress..

Comment: yes i have already tried this.. but when if one of the variables is null .. then the output is like.. taj road, agra,,india,282001

Answer (score 33):

This solution should work for you:

Just put all variables into an array and filter all empty values out with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), then just [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) them by a comma, e.g.

```
$fulladdress = implode(",", array_filter([$street, $city, $state, $country, $zipcode])) ;
```

Answer (score 4):

array_filter can be used to filter out FALSE, empty or Null string from the provided array.

Check here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

```
<?php

    $entry = array(
         0 => 'foo',
         1 => false,
         2 => -1,
         3 => null,
         4 => ''
    );

    print_r(array_filter($entry));
?>
```

The above code will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [2] => -1
)
```

Now implode resulting array with ',' so you get a string with all non-empty elements seperated by ,

Here is what I have used in my code :

```
$Matter_Client_Address_City_ST_Zip =      
    implode(",",array_filter([$Matter_Client_City, 
    $Matter_Client_State,$Matter_Client_Zip]));
```

the above code will output only non-empty fields seperated by a comma (,) so if city is blank, it would output CA,92620

Answer (score 1):

This code is not optimized, but it works :

```
<?php
    $abc = "abc";
    $bcd = null;
    $cde = "cde";



/**
 * concatenate some values
 * @param $values an array witch contains all values to concatenate
 */
function concat( $values = array() )
{
    //Look over all values
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
        //If current value is not null or empty, display it
        if ( !empty($values[$i]) )
            echo $values[$i];
        //If current value is not null AND if it is not the last value
        if ( !empty($values[$i]) && $i < count($values) -1 )
            echo ', ';
    }
}
concat(array($abc, $bcd, $cde));
```

Answer (score 0):

could help:

```
function concat_ws(){
    $ar=func_get_args();
    return implode(array_shift($ar), array_filter($ar)) ;
}
echo concat_ws(" - ", "hello", "", null, "world");
```

return : hello - world